# DXT1 compressed textures arent sopported on Iphone

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, error-handling, build, textures

I've been trying to make an IOS build on unity but each time I tried I get this message "DXT1 compressed textures are not supported when publishing to iPhone"
I have already change the compression of all my textures to "RGB COMPRESSED PVRTC 4bits" but I still get the same error. based on some answers I found here I have to delete the default checker gray but I have no idea what it is or where I can find it. so if anyone knows please help me...

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't resolved this issue yet then try these solutions.

1- First change all textures from DXT1 to any other compression that is    supported for Iphone. Am using RGBA Compressed ASTC.

2- Check all your materials, there will be any material which is using unity built in texture named "Default-Checker-Gray". Just delete this texture from that material and it will resolve your issue. image is also attached below for quick reference.

[Default Checker Gray Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBH7h.png)

Option 2 resolved my issue and now am able to build xcode project.